# Find a function $h$ such that $g(x) =\langle f, h \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $P_2(\mathbb R)$ be an inner product space with $\langle f, h \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}f(t)h(t)dt$. Let $g(f) = f(0) + f'(1)$. Find $h(t)$ such that $g(f) = \langle f,h \rangle$.

I tried representing $f$ as $f(t) = at^2+bt +c$ then $f(0) = c, f'(1) = 2a + b$. But I'm not sure if these are the right steps, and if they are, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I suppose that the inner product is $\langle f,h \rangle$; right?

Comment: Is $P_2(\Bbb R)$ the space of degree (at most) $2$ real polynomials?

Comment: @EmilioNovati yes

Comment: @arthur yes youre right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to find $h \in P_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$g(f_i) = \langle f_i,h \rangle \text{ for } i = 0,1,2$$
where $f_i(t) = t^i, \beta = \{f_0,f_1,f_2\}$ is the standard basis for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$, as for the rest of $f \in P_2(\mathbb{R})$ the statement follows from the linearity of $g$ and $\langle\cdot,h\rangle$.

Let $h(t) = c_0 + c_1t + c_2t^2$. Then we have
$$g(f_0) = \langle f_0,h\rangle \implies 1 = c_0 + \frac{1}{2}c_1 + \frac{1}{3}c_2$$
$$g(f_1) = \langle f_1,h\rangle \implies 1 = \frac{1}{2} c_0 + \frac{1}{3}c_1 + \frac{1}{4}c_2$$
$$g(f_2) = \langle f_2,h\rangle \implies 2 = \frac{1}{3}c_0 + \frac{1}{4}c_1 + \frac{1}{5}c_2$$

Solving
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3}\\\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4}\\\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c_0\\c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$
gives
$$c_0 = 33, c_1 = -204, c_2 = 210$$
and finally
$$h(t) = 33 - 204t + 210t^2$$